# How do I get AutoMapper to map classes whose type isn't known at compile time?

Tags: c#, automapper

Let's say that I have a class `Schedule` that contains a property called `Event` that's a nested class. Let's say that there are many types of events, so the actual value of the property would be some subclass (or descendant) of `Event`. The event could be a `Conference` or a `ReligiousCeremony` or yada yada yada.

Now let's say that all of these classes are in an "old" namespace and I'm using AutoMapper to convert these into updated version in a "new" namespace. (Ideal use case for AutoMapper.) `v1.Schedule` maps to `v2.Schedule` and `v1.Conference` maps to `v2.Conference` and so on.

The issue I have is that because `Schedule.Event` isn't of type `v1.Conference`, AutoMapper isn't identifying it as an object type it can map. Specifically, my class definitions are coming from an XSD and the `Schedule.Event` property is of type `object`.

Is there a way to get AutoMapper to inspect the actual type of an `object` and apply the appropriate mapping?

My current work-around (which another developer is testing right now) is as follows:

```
var v2Schedule = mapper.Map<v2.Schedule>(v1Schedule);
if (v2Schedule.Event is v1.Conference) { v2Schedule.Event = mapper.Map<v2.Conference>(v2Schedule.Event as v1.Conference); }
if (v2Schedule.Event is v1.ReligiousCeremony) { v2Schedule.Event = mapper.Map<v2.ReligiousCeremony>(v2Schedule.Event as v1.ReligiousCeremony); }
```

(I know about switching on object type, but that's a c#7 feature and I'm still in c#6.)

Comment: Not really answering your question, but I always wondered why "auto" mapper needs any configuration at all.  It's not really "auto".  A suggestion Automapper has given is to use reflection to create the mapping on the fly.  Food for thought :)  https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/9.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#automapper-no-longer-creates-maps-automatically-createmissingtypemaps-and-conventions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [docs](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Mapping-inheritance.html), it seems you can tell AutoMapper about the inheritance like so:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
       //Other mapping

        cfg.CreateMap<v1.Event, v2.Event>() //or even <object, v2.Event>
            .Include<v1.Conference, v2.Conference>()
            .Include<v1.ReligiousCeremony, v2.ReligiousCeremony>();
            
        cfg.CreateMap<v1.Conference, v2.Conference>();
        cfg.CreateMap<v1.ReligiousCeremony, v2.ReligiousCeremony>();
    });
```